# how to add items to the spinner dynamically at first index in android?

Tags: android, spinner

I put entries in spinner via XML.

Now i am want to insert a item on first index of spinner by pragmatically.

is it possible?

```
    ddlParkingType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ddlParkingType);

    TextView tv=new TextView(this);tv.setText("All");
    ArrayAdapter<String>  adapter=(ArrayAdapter<String>)ddlParkingType.getAdapter();
    adapter.add("Alll");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    ddlCarType= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ddlCarType);
    String arr[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.arrCarType);
    String arrN[] = new String[arr.length + 1];
    arrN[0] = "All";

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arrN[i + 1] = arr[i];
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ctx,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrN);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    ddlCarType.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using [ArrayAdapter.insert(T object, int index)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#insert%28T,%20int%29) as:

```
adapter.insert("New Value",0);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String[] newArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ARRAYNAME);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("All");
    for (int j = 0; j < newArray.length; j++) {
        list.add(newArray[j]);
    }

newArray = (String[]) list.toArray();
```

Then use can set adapter with newArray.

Comment: Last line is wrong newArray = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);